# Promise chains aren't being executed all the way through

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to do an integration test on a function that manages users. The calls it makes are asynchronous but Jest seems to be cutting out after I add the test user and check the details.

```
  it("runs lifecycle", async done => {
    // expect.assertions(1);
    function check(a, b, c) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(a, b, c);
        if (a != b) reject(c);
        console.error(a, b, c);
        resolve();
      });
    }
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      user.add(testUser).then(() => {
        user.get(testUser.id).then(out => {
          check(out, testUser, "adding").then(() => {
            user.update(testUser1).then(() => {
              user
                .get(testUser1.id)
                .then(out => check(out, testUser1, "update"))
                .then(() => {
                  user.delete(testUser.id).then(() => {
                    user
                      .get(testUser1.id)
                      .then(out => check(out, null, "delete"))
                      .then(() => {
                        resolve();
                        done();
                      });
                  });
                });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }).then(() => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy;
      done();
    });
    done();
```

`testUser` and `testUser1` are objects with some of their properties changed. I have tested this outside of Jest and the code runs fine.

```
console.log user.js:68
    Successfully created new user: test

  console.log user.test.js:26
    { id: 'test',
      email: 'you@me.com',
      first: 'Wilhelm',
      last: 'Erasmus',
      phone: '+271234567' } { id: 'test',
      email: 'yo@me.com',
      first: 'Wilhelm',
      last: 'Erasmus',
      phone: '+277654321' } 'adding'

  console.error user.test.js:28
    { id: 'test',
      email: 'you@me.com',
      first: 'Wilhelm',
      last: 'Erasmus',
      phone: '+271234567' } { id: 'test',
      email: 'yo@me.com',
      first: 'Wilhelm',
      last: 'Erasmus',
      phone: '+277654321' } 'adding'

 FAIL  ./user.test.js (7.269s)
  User APIs
    ✕ runs lifecycle (2779ms)

  ● User APIs › runs lifecycle

    Error

      adding

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.916s
Ran all test suites.
  console.log user.js:114
    Successfully deleted test

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Comment: Avoid the `.then`-as-callback anti-pattern - *return* the `Promise` so the next `.then` can handle it instead, for much flatter code. (or, for this much nesting, consider `await` instead)

Comment: First off, do `fn().then().then().then()` instead of deep nesting.  Second, make sure you return any promise from with a `.then()` so that it is inserted into the promise chain.  `fn().then(val => { return someOtherfn()}).then(...).then(...)`.  If you don't return it, then it's just an independent promise chain that has no connection at all to the parent except when it started and it's completion is not part of the parent chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 it seems to stop executing right after the first invocation of check() the update() has a promise implemented. I've tried both nested and unnested promises but neither work.

Comment: What does "stop executing" mean?

Comment: @jfriend00 testing halts and any errors after this point don't get accounted for.

Comment: Well, if `check()` rejects, what do you expect to happen?  There's no `.catch()` so when `check()` rejects, the promise chain has nothing else to do.  I still don't get the problem here.  Your code needs to be rewritten into a chain that is actually linked and has error handling.  Can't really do much more with it until that happens.

Comment: If the error is "adding" then it failed on that check, correct? What was the output of console.log(a, b, c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I'm not sure why this solution works and I am happy to accept an answer that explains it better.

```
    var addUser = user.add(testUser);
    var checkAdd = addUser
      .then(() => user.get(testUser.id))
      .then(check1 => check(check1, testUser, "Add"));

    var updateUser = checkAdd.then(() => user.update(testUser1));
    var checkUpdate = updateUser
      .then(() => user.get(testUser1.id))
      .then(check2 => check(check2, testUser1, "Add"));

    var deleteUser = checkUpdate.then(() => user.delete(testUser1.id));
    var checkDelete = deleteUser.then(() => {
      expect(user.exists).resolves.toBeFalsy;
    });
    return Promise.all([
      addUser,
      checkAdd,
      updateUser,
      checkUpdate,
      deleteUser,
      checkDelete
    ]);
```